# How to call entity(as[String]) from postman scala spray

Tags: scala, postman, spray

I am new to scala and spray. I'm trying to hit POST api from Postman. From front-end it is working but how can I hit from postman.

```
POST /api/admin/users/:userId/update-role
path("update-role") {
                  postCsrf {
                    entity(as[String]) { role => ctx =>
                      // TODO: This is not the optimal way to do this, but with the 2.4 time crunch, it's going in as tech debt.
                      }
                } ~
```

[image: Request from Postman]

[image: Request from Front-end]

Comment: spray is dead. Long live akka-http. Are you using akka-http maybe?

Comment: what does postman return when you send the request. Postman can generate curl code for the request. can you post it too?

Comment: it says 404 not found. I've added postman image

Comment: From Postman you're hitting localhost, while in the app you're accessing some "real-world" url. Are you sure that your local server is up and running correctly, with the same code?

Comment: yes it is localhost. i mean it happens whatever is the host. on local also same 404